Is Notification endpoint in USB CDC required?
Usecase
I am implementing USB Host using GD32F405 MCU to communicate with USB Devices, that implement CDC protocol.
I have a case, where USB Device is Android-based device. We have UI APP designed by 3rd party and need to integrate that device as a slave device.
Protocol is simple request-response one with base64-based transport.
I have developed app to reliably work with that android (reconnect on failure etc.).
In USB Ep0 i perform such operations in given order:

Request device descriptor to get Ep0 size
Set device address to 2 (1 is reserved)
Request configuration descriptor
Select desired (the only) configuration

The problem
Normally, this system (Android + MCU) boots and starts it's exchange correctly, but at some point I see no reaction from interface. I have requested highly-detailed logs from android developer.
I noted that after 1199 bytes of transferred data (MCU to Android) there is a change in parcel length - one parcel is truncated and all the other parcels (retries) since that point are containing only one character: * (asterisk). The first invalid parcel is truncated, so it contains valid request start and then an asterisk: \x02!AAc*. That asterisk is exactly 1200'th byte transferred. The start of the line matches with MCU logs.
It feels like Android app receives truncated lines because of incorrect buffer release and I should send some extra control command(s) to make it work reliably in long run.
To bisect the problem we have tested the same Android device with Linux machine in "COM-bridge" setup and everything worked perfectly with the similar requests (generated by MCU). Schematic is:
MCU (UART) <--> USB-UART <--> (ttyUSB0) PC (ttyACM0) <--> Android device
PC here was running simple pyserial-based script to work as a relay. Wireshark at usbmon shows nothing unusual.
The Question
What should i do to make MCU work correctly with Android, just like it works with the PC CDC driver? Is there any required requests missing?
Tech details
Our interface contains such descriptors (as listed by lsusb -v):
Interface Association:
  bLength                 8
  bDescriptorType        11
  bFirstInterface         1
  bInterfaceCount         2
  bFunctionClass          2 Communications
  bFunctionSubClass       2 Abstract (modem)
  bFunctionProtocol       1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
  iFunction               8 CDC Serial
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        1
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           1
  bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
  bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
  bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
  iInterface              6 CDC Abstract Control Model (ACM)
  CDC Header:
    bcdCDC               1.10
  CDC Call Management:
    bmCapabilities       0x00
    bDataInterface          2
  CDC ACM:
    bmCapabilities       0x02
      line coding and serial state
  CDC Union:
    bMasterInterface        1
    bSlaveInterface         2 
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
    bmAttributes            3
      Transfer Type            Interrupt
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x000a  1x 10 bytes
    bInterval               9
Interface Descriptor:
  bLength                 9
  bDescriptorType         4
  bInterfaceNumber        2
  bAlternateSetting       0
  bNumEndpoints           2
  bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
  bInterfaceSubClass      0 [unknown]
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 
  iInterface              7 CDC ACM Data
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval               0
  Endpoint Descriptor:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType         5
    bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
    bmAttributes            2
      Transfer Type            Bulk
      Synch Type               None
      Usage Type               Data
    wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
    bInterval               0

There are also a MTP descriptor, but it is not releveant.
I am performing IN and OUT operations on Bulk endpoints:

IN is performed each 10 ms or faster, if there is any new data in previous IN exchange.
OUT is performed when there is any data available (synchronized using circular buffer).
I am not using Interrupt endpoint as it is not required by my logic, but i have tried to poll in 20 ms intervals - it does not fix the problem and I get only 2 messages at port open from Android side.


You seem to be phrasing this question as if the MCU is causing the problem, but that's not obvious.  I'd guess it's more likely that the Android code is buggy.  Either way, we can't really help you unless you show the code.
